# Ansible Synchronize - run task with different remote user

Tags: ansible, synchronization

I apologize in advance if this is documented somewhere or on the site - I could not find a solution and so I'm asking here.

I'm trying to use Ansible's synchronize module to pull files from a remote host, like so:

```
- hosts: Server.A
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    synchronize:
      mode: pull
      src: "file/to/pull"
      dest: "path/to/destination"
    delegate_to: NAS
```

That is, I want the NAS host to SSH into Server.A and pull the files I'd like to upload.

The problem is, the NAS has a non-default user (admin).

I set the NAS's admin user via the inventory file, and I can communicate with the NAS ok.

However, when I run the `synchronize` task, it attempts to login to the source server (Server.A) with the admin user, which does not exist, and fails.

I've tried changing the `remote_user`, `become` the module's `set_remote_user` settings, in the playbook, the hosts file and the host_vars, but I can't get it to work and find it very confusing.

How would I go about running the `synchronize` command as a different remote user instead of the local one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From `ansible-doc synchronize`:

> The user and permissions for the synchronize `src` are those of the user running the Ansible task on the local host (or the remote_user for a delegate_to host when delegate_to is used).

> The user and permissions for the synchronize `dest` are those of the `remote_user` on the destination host or the `become_user` if `become=yes` is active.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried setting the `remote_user` setting on Server.A both in the playbook and in the inventory file - and the rsync user stays the same - instead of `admin@ip`, it just shows `ip` when examining the process.